# how to add servlet-api.jar in an ofbiz application?

Tags: java, servlets, jar, import, ofbiz

I wrote some java classes and used some servlet keywords. but it is not being recognized. I tried importing javax.servlet.*; but eclipse said it can't be resolved.

I'm not really sure but I tried to look up tomcat inside ofbiz to get the servlet-api.jar but I can't find it.

I tried rebuilding and cleaning the ofbiz project but it can't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download and add j2ee.jar in your classpath
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadj2eejar.htm

Comment: yep, i'll do this. but this will have portability problems when it gets deployed aye?

Comment: what type of portability? I have already configuared and write class in ofbiz and it gives no error

Comment: i mean, if i use "add external jar" and the code needs to be passed on to a different user. that would cause him some resolving problems. but for this instance, this would suffice. thanks for the help.